# Converting String to Double from ListBox to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, type-conversion

```
// Calculating and diplaying pricing in list.
for (double MAX = 4.25; MAX >= MIN; MAX -= 0.05)
{
    Price = (X * MAX);
    prices = Price.ToString("c");
    listFinances.Items.Add(prices);
}

---

private void listFinances_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string TotalPrice = listFinances.SelectedItem.ToString();
    double stateIncentive = (Convert.ToDouble(TotalPrice) / 4);
    txtStateTax.Text = stateIncentive.ToString();
}
```

So I'm trying to take a `ListBox` of string currency values, turn them into a double, divide them by 4, and display the result in a `TextBox`. The user will select the `ListBox` value and the program should automatically divide by 4 and display.

It's not working however. The program always does an exception throw when you click the `ListBox` item. The exception is thrown at:

```
double stateIncentive = (Convert.ToDouble(TPrice) / 4);
```

saying that:

> It's not in the correct format.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Post the exact exception that is thrown. Also I cannot find `TPrice` anywhere in your code, you need to post all relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add your strings with the currency symbol. If you want to parse the string back to a double (but [it is better use a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)) you need to tell the conversion that you have that symbol and ignore it

```
private void listFinances_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string TotalPrice = listFinances.SelectedItem.ToString();
    decimal stateIncentive = decimal.Parse(TotalPrice, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) / 4);
    txtStateTax.Text = stateIncentive.ToString();
}
```

I have used decimal instead of double because  the decimal type is more adapt to handle money values. I suggest to make the same change in the for..loop that fill the list (Just use the suffix `m` to specify constant decimal values (IE. `4.25m` and `0.05m`)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a currency string to double so you should Try like this:

```
double stateIncentive = (Double.Parse(TotalPrice, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency) / 4);
```

Or would be better if using `decimal` (Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) to know why):

```
decimal stateIncentive = (decimal.Parse(TotalPrice, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency) / 4);
```

The style parameter defines the style elements (such as white space, thousands separators, and **currency** symbols) refer to MSDN:[`Double.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx)